# CryptographicException in CSP components under Temporary or Mandatory user profile

Tags: c#, .net, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I have a .Net component which I am maintaining which makes use of the [FromXmlString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.dsa.fromxmlstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of the DSA class.  This works fine, most of the time.  Under certain circumstances, it fails with this exception:  "CryptographicException: The profile for the user is a temporary profile".

The error is imprecise, because the actual circumstance is a [Mandatory Profile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  However, I can replicate the issue by testing with a Temporary Profile (I "break" a user profile, so that a temporary profile gets set up at login).

The full stack trace looks like this:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The profile for the user is a temporary profile.
    at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle
    at System.Security.Cryptography.DSACryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters
    at System.Security.Cryptography.DSA.FromXmlString
    at MyMethod
```

Ultimately CreateProvHandle is calling an internal method named System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._OpenCSP .

I theorize that the exception is being raised because the various CSP methods expect to write keys values to the user's profile, and as the profile is temporary (or mandatory), those keys would be lost.

For my use case, it does not matter if the keys are lost when the user logs off.

So my question, is there any way to tell the cryptographic subsystem that I do not care about the transient nature of the profile, and that I'd like the operation to go ahead anyway ?